# Getting this information for GISTIC2

Tags: wgs, copy-number

Long time I am struggling how to provide ***GISTIC2*** required input like `Num_Probes` and `Segment_Mean`

I have called somatic copy number by scatngs and I have copy number output file (attached);

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6nef2v1j2di6q6/my.copynumber.caveman.csv?dl=0

This is few lines of scatngs copy number output

```
1,1,13116,665401,2,1,3,1
2,1,668374,96324627,2,1,2,1
3,1,96326095,96419709,2,1,1,0
```

In scatngs reference paper says in this file we have

```
Segment number

Chromosome

Start position (origin-1)

End position (origin-1)

Major copy number—normal

Minor copy number—normal

Major copy number—tumor

Minor copy number—tumor
```

scatngs also returns another output like below

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7i28vooixdp06c2/WTSI-OESO_121_1pre.copynumber.txt?dl=0

```
Chromosome  Position    Log R   segmented LogR  BAF segmented BAF   Copy number Minor allele    Raw copy number
rs62635286  1   13116   -0.0290741822638953 0.245246748556562   0.25    NA  3   1   2.35806652809599
rs75454623  1   14930   0.402869048014209   0.245246748556562   0.3095  NA  3   1   4.14031506947036
```

I am wondering how I can get `Num_Probes` and `Segment_Mean` From this files?

People say

```
Segment_Mean = log2(tumour copy number / 2)
```

So, does that mean I should add up `Major copy number—tumor` and

`Minor copy number—tumor` to get tumour copy number? for getting Num_Probes what should I do?

***EDITED***

> people says
>
> scatngs uses read counts at SNPs to generate calls and so the
>   locations of the SNPs is what I need to
>   generate the number of markers in each segment. (eg each SNP = 1
>   marker).
>
> Do they mean, for instance if the position of SNP  rs62635286 is
>   13116, so the num_prob is 13116?

Any help please?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Cross-posted on GitHub for some reason: https://github.com/cancerit/ascatNgs/issues/84

Comment: I mentioned a cross-post. That does not stop anyone from reading the question or helping you.

Comment: Mentioning a cross post is hardly negative feedback or reason to ignore a post that belongs on bioinfo SE.

Comment: Did you try reading the GISTIC2 documentation about how to get the data in that format? Or perhaps they point to a known file extension (or a weird one from only a single program) I tried searching on a couple of website about these required Num_probes but couldn't find anything. Are you using [this](ftp://ftp.broadinstitute.org/pub/GISTIC2.0/) software or other with the same name?

Comment: I read GISTIC2 documentation, there is nothing about how to get required format. Exactly I am trying the same software you are referring to. People using GISTIC in broad institute produce their CN by this method that returns format for GISTIC https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/documentation/article?id=9143#1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the software to generate the segmentation file;

For example I have used scatngs for segmentation that for sample returns

```
Segment number
Chromosome
Start position (origin-1)
End position (origin-1)
Major copy number—normal
Minor copy number—normal
Major copy number—tumor
Minor copy number—tumor
```

By  log2(Major copy number—tumor +  Minor copy number—tumor /ploidy of each sample) you would get segment mean

For number of probes

```
The number of probes depends on where the data came from.
1) From SNP arrays:  Number of array probes within each segment.
2) From exon capture data:   Probes are the ends of exons and so the number of probes are equal to the number of exons  X 2.
3) From whole genome sequencing:  Probes are the boundaries of bins used to generate the copy number data and so the number of probes are equal to the number of bins +
```

For example in my case for scatngs

```
Each SNP is a marker, and so you have to count how many of these SNPs are on each segment
```

I have asked this question in

[Extracting the number SNP in each range](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/8531/extracting-the-number-snp-in-each-range?noredirect=1#comment11314_8531)